# Are objects passed by reference or value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In [this post](http://www.websanova.com/tutorials/jquery/10-coding-tips-to-write-superior-jquery-plugins), the author is using:

```
$.fn.wPaint = function(settings) {
   settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, settings || {});
```

Q: Wouldn't that overwrite the settings variable the calling scope? I would think you'd want to create a new variable, which would mean that you'd have a total of 3 variables:

1. The Default settings in the closure scope
2. The settings in the arguments
3. The settings in the local scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings argument is a reference to a variable in the calling scope.  Inside your function you are assigning a new object to the settings variable, this breaks the reference and points the local variable to a new value in the local scope.  If you modified settings, without assigning to it, it would affect the settings in the calling scope.  The settings in the arguments is the settings in the local scope.

Comment: OK, thanks.  So if he had not used $.extend, then he WOULD have been overwriting it?  That seems oftly brittle.  In https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/jquery.boilerplate.js, they are using the this scope.

Comment: @Pedro, I don't understand your question.  Any time you have `settings =` you will break any reference settings has to another object.

Comment: I think what I'm seeing is that if the calling program passes a string instead of an object, then I would be overwriting it.  I'm not sure about that though.

Comment: I think it's just a bad idea to use the same variable name to reference two different scopes, unless you explicitly say which scope you're talking about - either the local scope or the arguments scope.

Comment: @Pedro There isn't really a difference -- or a need to identify an "arguments scope." All arguments are part of the local scope of the function, same as any `var` defined within it. Aside from the values they're given, they have no ties to calling scope.

Comment: @Pedro, I have no idea what you mean by "arguments scope", I have never heard such a term.

Answer (score 4):

Objects are always passed by reference.

In your code, you're just say that the local variable `settings` will point to a different objects. So you pass the object by reference then you said "ok, I'm not interested in that reference anymore, point to that other object".

To be clear, if you have:

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
var b = a;

b = {bar: "foo"};
```

You're not "destroying" neither "change" the original object `{foo: "bar"}`. You just point `b` to a different object, `a` will still point to the original one, so won't be affected.

It's the same in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, all arguments are passed "by value." The key is that, in the case of `settings`, the value is a reference.

This is not the same as "by reference." It can be similar as you are still referencing the same object in memory:

```
$.fn.wPaint = function(settings) {
    settings.foo = 'foo'; // updates object in calling scope
    // etc.
};
```

But, changing `settings` itself only changes its own value to a new reference:

```
$.fn.wPaint = function(settings) {
    settings = $.extend(...);
};
```

Comment: "the value is a reference".  It's not an optical illusion - it just looks like one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this you'll need to pass `setting` inside an object `{}`.

```
$.fn.wPaint = function(settingsContainer) {
    settingsContainer.settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, settings || {});
```

-

```
var settingsContainer = {settings:originalSettings};
$.fn.wPaint(settingsContainer);
originalSettings = settingsContainer.settings;
```

Comment: I don't think I want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `settings` object as the first argument to the function `$.extend`:

```
$.fn.wPaint = function(settings) {
    $.extend(settings, defaultSettings, settings || {});
}
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/26Bst/ and read the [API entry](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for more details.

Comment: That's weird, because I console.log(obj) and I get three(3) variables inside of the obj object, but when I console.log(obj.other), it says undefined.

Comment: Where, exactly, are you calling `console.log` on the script execution flow? Could you provide a jsFiddle for that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fg3MG/1/  Here you can see that Object contains three values.

Comment: This behavior shows the whole point here. The `console.log(obj)` is logging the reference to the object, not a copy of its state on that particular moment (in this case, on your first call to the function). By the end of the execution, the Object contains three values, this is why you see the same output on both calls.